# Encryption based on a tree structure

Tags: encryption

This may be more of an academic question but I've got a tree of users like such:

```
1->2
1->3
2->4
2->5
```

Each user needs to be able to examine themselves and their subgroup there is no limit to the number of subgroups and there's no limit to the number of users. No user should be able to examine any other user's subgroup. So even though 2 and 3 are the same level 2 cannot examine 3's subs and vice versa.

What encryption scheme would let me do the fewest number of checks to retrieve the whole tree?

Answer (score 1):

Example graphic of the item arrangement for the following description.

```
         /- 4
   /- 2 -|
   |     \- 5
1 -|
   |
   \- 3
```

1. Encrypt each item with its own key.
2. Include the key of each item in its parent.
3. To allow access to any item and its subtree, supply the key to that item.

To allow access to item 2 and its sub-items provide the encryption to item 2.
Then sub-items 4 and 5 can be accessed because their keys are in item 2.

Allowing access to item 3 will not provide the keys to items 1, 2, 4 and 5.

If including the key in each parent item is not desirable create a shadow tree just for the keys.